# Use reactive variable to plot histogram using plotly

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am trying to make an App in which a user can browse a file and then select any particular column from the list of column names and a histogram will be plotted. Further, i want to give the user an option to remove outlier which is a checkboxinput. If the checkbox is clicked the outliers are removed and the histogram is plotted again. In short, the histogram reacts to the selection made by the user in the checkbox. I am not able to plot the graph when an observeEvent is observed on the checkbox. I think my data is not referenced appropriately when i create it as reactive.

I am not to sure how to exactly use reactivity here. If i do not use reactivity then i get an error that my data set is not available under the observeEvent function (it may be case of local function )

```
df_data <- reactiveValues(data= NULL)

observeEvent(input$filename,{
  df_data$data <- data.frame(read.csv(input$filename$datapath))
  updateSelectInput(session,"field_mapping",choices = colnames(df_data$data))
  updateCheckboxInput(session,"outlier_removal",value = TRUE)
})

observeEvent(input$outlier_removal,{
if(input$outlier_removal)
{ cash_diff <- removeOutliers(createCashDiff(as.vector(df_data$data[,input$field_mapping]),input$percent_change)) }
else { cash_diff <- removeOutliers(createCashDiff(as.vector(df_data$data[,input$field_mapping]),input$percent_change)) }
output$Histogram <- renderPlotly({ plotDiff(cash_diff) })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be trying to plot from inside an `observe` block. Even more so, things inside the expression (second argument) of `observeEvent` is done explicitly without reactivity side-effect, so it's being insulated/masked, so to speak.

Try this:

```r
df_data <- reactiveValues(data= NULL)

observeEvent(input$filename,{
  df_data$data <- data.frame(read.csv(input$filename$datapath))
  updateSelectInput(session,"field_mapping",choices = colnames(df_data$data))
  updateCheckboxInput(session,"outlier_removal",value = TRUE)
})

df_data_filtered <- reactive({
  x <- createCashDiff(as.vector(df_data$data[,input$field_mapping]),input$percent_change)
  if (input$outlier_removal) x <- removeOutliers(x)
  x
})

output$Histogram <- renderPlotly({ plotDiff(df_data_filtered()) })
```

Side note: you are doing precisely the same function call in both side of your `if (input$outlier_removal)` condition. Does this mean your `createCashDiff` or `removeOutliers` functions get the `input$outlier_removal` value themselves? I suggest this would be a bad move, for two reasons:

1. Functions like those should be agnostic to being used inside or outside of shiny, so you can develop and test in a console/testing (non-shiny) environment. Embedding reliance on "reactivity" (even just `input$`) inside the functions is constraining the functions' potential; and
2. In general, good practice on writing functions involves ensuring they never try to access variables or objects that are not either (a) explicitly passed to them, or (b) defined within the function (directly or via another function call). When you have a function access variables outside of its immediate scope, testing and reproducibility become more complex and significantly harder to troubleshoot *when* they misbehave.

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans. You are a genius. I need to study more about reactivity to use it in my apps. Your explanations is wonderful. This works now. And, yes.. sorry i placed the removeOutliers function under both the condition.. it should be only when the input$outlier_removal is true.

Comment: Yes it does. I was able to run and test the app using it. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Reactivity is a very powerful -- and at times, chaotic -- tool. I find myself manually drawing dependency flow diagrams, taking into account `isolate` and even accidental read/write actions. Eventually, I look at [`reactlog`](https://github.com/rstudio/reactlog) to see what `shiny` thinks the reactivity relationships are, and then realize why a single change in one field might cause a table or plot to re-render multiple times. In general, I find it best to *"do data simply in a `reactive` block, then rely on it in simple `render*` functions"*.